# How to create proper completion handler for server login in swift?

Tags: swift, api, authentication

I have an api manager class in my swift application and it has a server login with username and password.
I want to know how to create a completion handler for it that when the server responses with 200 status code, the function handles that response and for example performs a segue in the viewcontroller.
I did not find any tutorials for this. Thanks for your help!

EDIT 1:
What i need is: The completion handler is immediately run when the function is called. I want the completion handler run after server responds.

And this is my login function:

```
public class func Login(username: String, password: String, complitionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {

        let urlS = "http://server.com/" + "login.php"
        let url = URL(string: urlS)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let body = "username=\(username.lowercased())&password=\(password)"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error!)
                print("error")
                logedIn = 2
                return
            }
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJson = json {
                    let code = parseJson["status"] as! String
                    if code == "200" {

                        print("loged inn")
                        logedIn = 1
                    }else if code == "400" {
                        print("uuuser/pass error")
                        logedIn = 0
                    }
                }

            }catch{
                print("json error")
                logedIn = 2
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        complitionHandler(logedIn)
    }

    }
```

And how i call the function in my ViewController:

```
Manager.Login(username: "1", password: "1") { (i) in
            switch i {
            case 0:
                print("user/pass error")
            case 1:
                print("loged in")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMain", sender: self)
            case 2:
                print("json error")
            default:
                ()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your edit is unclear. The code you posted doesn't even call the completion handler so how can it be called immediately? And show how you are calling this `Login` function.

Comment: I am super annoyed with this problem for months, thanks for your help @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all of the pieces in place. You just need to move your call to the completion handler to the correct place:

```
        }catch{
            print("json error")
            logedIn = 2
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            complitionHandler(logedIn)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Also note that method names should start with lowercase letters so your `Login` function should be named `login`.

Now you can use this `login` method like:

```
login(username: someUsername, password: somePassword) { (result) in
    if result == 1 {
        // success - do your segue
    } else if result == 0 {
        // bad username/password
    } else {
        // some error
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is when i have the completionHandler(logedIn) it doesn't give me the result the server has given. after some seconds prints the desired logedin result. i mean the block of code written in completion handler is immediately run when the func has been called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please edit your question with how you call your `login` method. Compare with how I show you in my answer.

Comment: Your latest edit now includes a call to the completion handler. The problem is you put it in the wrong place. Please read my answer again.